# Is there a significant difference between Indian and Chinese star anise?

Tags: ingredient-selection

I’ve just bought some star anise, but I'm not sure of its origin.   It smells zingy which kind of reminds me of Chinese food.

Taste-wise, is there a difference between Indian and Chinese star anise? I wanted the Indian one, as per a recipe, but I’m wondering if I have the Chinese one and if that will give the same taste the recipe intended?

Comment: The culinary star anise is _Illicium verum_. Just to be clear, in English the plant called the "Japanese star anise" is a different species, _Illicium anisatum_, which is toxic and not fit for consumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, star anise is star anise.  I don't think the origin matters much for your recipe, but there might be a marginal difference.  I've never paid much attention to the origin of my star anise.

Answer (score 2):

The star anise shrub (Illicium verum) [originates in China](https://www.thespruceeats.com/what-is-star-anise-1328525), so it's all going to be pretty similar regardless of where the pods you bought are actually grown; where I live distributors don't even label origin for it.  Nor can I find a single online publication source that mentions any differentiation of star anise by origin.